# Neo4j recursive cypher query resulting in nested JSON structure

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to figure out cypher query in order to get nested JSON structure as a result. Below I present an example of the graph.

[image: Graph]

```
MATCH (user:User {name:"User_1"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[rel*]->(subUser:User)
RETURN *
```

Query above allows me to get all the nodes and relationships required to transform everything to JSON structure I want but that requires me to process everything after getting the result from querying the database. To achieve that I need to match identity of nodes and relationship in order to get the nested JSON.
I was wondering if it is possible to achieve that directly from building cypher query.
Important thing is that we do not know how many levels of **"child" Users** we have starting from **User_1**

Expected JSON structure:

```
{ 
    "user": "User_1",
    "children": [
        {
            "user": "User_2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "user": "User_5",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },{
            "user": "User_3",
            "children": [
                {
                    "user": "User_6",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },{
            "user": "User_4",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

**Is it possible?**

Comment: using `APOC` plugin makes it simple. Look for [`apoc.convert.toTree`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.convert/apoc.convert.toTree/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by @nimrod serok, you can use the `apoc.convert.toTree` method, it will give you the tree-structured JSON, as desired, with one caveat, the keys of the JSON will be different. For the data:

```
MERGE (u1:User{name: 'User1'})
MERGE (u2:User{name: 'User2'})
MERGE (u3:User{name: 'User3'})
MERGE (u4:User{name: 'User4'})
MERGE (u5:User{name: 'User5'})
MERGE (u6:User{name: 'User6'})
MERGE (u1)-[:POINTS]->(u2)-[:POINTS]->(u5)
MERGE (u1)-[:POINTS]->(u3)-[:POINTS]->(u6)
MERGE (u1)-[:POINTS]->(u4)
```

The query:

```
MATCH (user:User {name:"User1"})
OPTIONAL MATCH path = (user)-[:POINTS*]->(subUser:User)
WITH collect(path) AS paths
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths, true, {nodes: {User: ['name']}})
YIELD value
RETURN value
```

produces the output:

```
{
  "_type": "User",
  "name": "User1",
  "_id": 4,
  "points": [
    {
      "_type": "User",
      "name": "User3",
      "_id": 6,
      "points": [
        {
          "_type": "User",
          "name": "User6",
          "_id": 9
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_type": "User",
      "name": "User2",
      "_id": 5,
      "points": [
        {
          "_type": "User",
          "name": "User5",
          "_id": 8
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_type": "User",
      "name": "User4",
      "_id": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

as you can see, the `relationship type` `POINTS`, comes in place of `children`, and the key `name` comes for the user name. The other fields `_type` and `_id` can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

apoc.convert.toTree() is certainly the best answer for the question you asked.

If one is interested in a text output then ORDPATH would be another solution. ORDPATH is a concatenated bitstring which sorts in hierarchical order. More on this at this [link](https://www.wai.md/post/ordpath-computing-genealogy-descendancy-trees). A Neo4j user defined function implementing this is at [GitHub](https://github.com/waigitdas/Neo4j-Genealogy-PlugIns/blob/main/java%20classes/graph/ordpath.java).